# Pytorch ConvNet loss remains unchanged and only one class is predicted

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

My ConvNet is only predicting a single class and the loss remains unchanged.

I have tried the following:

- added class weights to be proportional to the data sizes (1-(class occurrences/total data))
- adjusted learning rate attempting to find a sweet spot
- adjusted gamma (Multiplicative factor of learning rate decay)
- used gamma in the loss function, and not used it in loss function (Mainly have been experimenting with Adam)
- Tried a much more complex ConvNet than the 'Simple' one currently in use

I am unsure of where to go from here. It seems no matter what I try the Neural Net always predicts the same class (I have been able to get it to predict the other class by throwing the weights very out of proportion)

Below is the output from running my program. It should have all the relevant information in it to come up with some ideas as to how to fix it. If you need to see some of the source code or are curious about what the dataset looks like, please ask.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have been stumped on this issue for quite a while now. Thank you!

```
Train dataset length: 27569
Test dataset length: 4866

Image preprocessing: 
None
Input dimensions: 28 X 28
Output dimension: 2

Model: Simple
NeuralNetwork(
  (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
  (linear_relu_stack): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=784, out_features=512, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU()
    (2): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
    (3): ReLU()
    (4): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2, bias=True)
    (5): ReLU()
  )
)

Optimizer: Adam
Learning rate: 0.0001

Loss function: CEL
class weights: tensor([0.3481, 0.6519], device='cuda:0')
Multiplicative factor of learning rate decay: 0.0005

Train Epoch: 1 [0/27569 (0%)]   Loss: 3785.907959
Train Epoch: 1 [6400/27569 (23%)]   Loss: 0.693147
Train Epoch: 1 [12800/27569 (46%)]  Loss: 0.693147
Train Epoch: 1 [19200/27569 (70%)]  Loss: 0.693147
Train Epoch: 1 [25600/27569 (93%)]  Loss: 0.693147

Test set: Average loss: 0.0110, Accuracy: 3172/4866 (65%)

actual count: [3172, 1694]
predicted count: [4866, 0]
```

Comment: Not sure if related, but it is very unusual to have a ReLU after the last linear layer.

Comment: How is the `predicted count` in the training set? Could it be that you're not pre-processing the test set the same way you processed the training? We'll need some code to go any further than this.

Comment: Good thinking. The training count is [17780, 9789]. I readjusted the weights to reflect this and I am still getting the predicted total to all be of the first class. The test data and the train data are however preprocessed exactly the same. Allow me to edit the post with some source code. Thank you.

Comment: Is there anything specific you would like to see? There is so much source code I am not even sure what is relevant to the problem. Perhaps you would benefit from looking at the entire code base instead?

Comment: Just to make sure I got this right. When you said "training count is [17780, 9789]", you mean the "actual" or the "predicted" count? I was interested to know the "predicted", to understand if the model is training just fine (and the problem could be elsewhere) or if is collapsing.

Comment: Apologies. The 'training count' is how many instances there are of each class in the training data. So I am training with 17780 images of class '0' and 9789 images of class '1'. The 'actual_count' is the number of instances in the testing set. and the 'predicted_count' is what the nueral net is predicting (shows it predicts all the same class). So I am uncertain precicely what you are looking to see, but I hope that clears up that.

Comment: I see. I want "the predicted count in the training set", i.e., after you finish training, **make predictions on the training set (as a sanity check)** and let us know what is the "predicted count" for the training set.

Comment: Failed the sanity check. I gave the train_loader to my test and I was given the following: 
train count: [17780, 9789]
actual count: [17780, 9789]
predicted count: [27569, 0]

Comment: Then somehow the training is collapsing. Have you tried removing that last ReLU layer?

Comment: Although very poor results, you definetley helped me. I removed that layer and recieved the following: train target: [17780, 9789]
actual count: [17780, 9789]
predicted count: [27507, 62]. it is beginning to predict the second class somewhat. I can begin to experiment around and try and get better results but thank you so much you got me out of a stuck place. The entire time I didn't even think about the architecture because I copied it from online just expecting it to already work

Comment: Glad to know it helped. I added an answer for future readers (consider upvoting if it was helpful), as comments are second-class citizens in SO =] I also recommend you to tweak the LR and check if it helps.

Comment: "Second class citizens" I'm laughing out loud. Thank you. I am still new to designing CNN architectures, so that was overlooked from the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very uncommon to have a `ReLU` after the last `Linear` layer (where the logits come from). Consider removing it.

In addition, maybe your learning rate is too high. You could try tweaking it a little bit. Check if the loss decreases smoothly between the iterations (which is ideal in most cases), otherwise decrease it